# How do I access a dict value through key on Kivy Language?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

On my .py:

```
class DataGet(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DataGet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_get = {
            "FO2": 62,
            "Peek Pressure": 12,
            "Total Volume": 35,
            "PEEPe": 26,
            "Minute Volume": 98,
            "Respiratory Rate": 75,
        }
        self.updater = Thread(target=self.get_data, args=())

    get_fo2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    get_peepe = ObjectProperty(None)
    get_peek_pressure = ObjectProperty(None)
    get_minute_volume = ObjectProperty(None)
    get_total_volume = ObjectProperty(None)
    get_respiratory_rate = ObjectProperty(None)

    def get_data(self): #This is just a test function, not yet implemented
        while True:
            for data in self.data_get:
                self.data_get[data] = edg.update_data(self.data_get[data])
                print(self.data_get[data])
            print("###")
            print(f"fo2 = {self.data_get}")
            print("###")
            sleep(2)
```

On my .kv:

```
<DataGet>:
    get_fo2: get_fo2
    get_peepe: get_peepe
    get_peek_pressure: get_peek_pressure
    get_minute_volume: get_minute_volume
    get_total_volume: get_total_volume
    get_respiratory_rate: get_respiratory_rate
    on_kv_post: root.updater.start()
    BoxLayout:
        cols:1
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            cols:2
            orientation: "vertical"
            halign: "center"

            Label:
                text: f"FO2"

            Label:
                id: get_fo2
                font_size: 60
                text: f"{root.data_get["FO2"]}"
```

When I call execute the code, the terminal outputs:

```
     f"{root.data_get["FO2"]}"
                       ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which makes no much sense, unless it has a different way to call dict values on kv language. I've read through kivy's kv language documentation and didn't found any reference on how to declare and use dictionaries. Even tried in a different syntax, no success.

Comment: `f"{root.data_get['FO2']}"` There is nothing to document on the kivy part, it's a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: your question is simple silly mistake and already answered but it helped me a lot to understand how to use dictProperty in kivy lang. thank you for your example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must take care of your quotes:

```
     f"{root.data_get['FO2']}"
```

Comment: yeah, was just thinking about it right now. Just quotes...

Comment: @JohnAnderson Which is already mentioned in comments so no need to repeat same thing.

Comment: The answer is needed so that people searching `stack overflow` can see that this question has an accepted answer..

Comment: @JohnAnderson First, if you don't mention me with `@` I have no way of knowing you commented. Second, there is literally a flag for this type of questions: "Not reproducible or caused by a typo." Since it's a typo error, the likelihood of someone has the same typo and searched for exact same terms to find this question is almost 0. And when you flag it, it will be closed so noone will visit to answer the question.